# How to write a wsdl for a webservice that can return two types of response for the same operation?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

The OTA (Open Travel Association) spec says that the  OTA_HotelAvail webservice operation can return either an OTA_ErrorRS element or an OTA_HotelAvailReS element in the soap body. How can I specify in the wsdl that the same operation can return either of the above two elements in the soap body. They are using document literal style for their webservice.